# Servicestack request add param to every query

Tags: c#, servicestack

I want to modify the RequestURI in the request from a Servicestack 'JsonServiceClient', however, the request URI is readonly. The Restful API that i'm trying to use requires a 'apikey' be sent in the URI of the GET request, instead of in the headers like i would expect. I know i could create a base class such as 'CommonRequest' and put the 'apikey' in there, but that sounds wrong, and instead I should be modifying the request pre-execution.

I have tried using the request filters built into ServiceStack, but that doesn't let me modify the Request.

Any ideas?

Peter

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the Request but you can attach additional metadata to it by adding it to the `IRequest.Items` dictionary.

Comment: This doesn't allow me to add parameters to the URI though

Comment: @Peter no because the HTTP Request can't be modified